# Macro gets disabled if called using a vb script

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am trying to call my excel macro using vbs. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Test_PO.xls")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Run "C:\Folder\Test_PO.xls!Data_Analysis"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Now the problem here is that i am able to open the file but the macro somehow gets disabled here and shows me `'macro may not be present or may be disabled'`. I am sure i am calling correct macro name but as soon as the file is opened the Add-ins tab where i had configured the macro to run from gets dissapeared.This does not open if i open the file manually , i can see the tab and run the macro from the tab itself. Any suggestions how i could overcome this problem and get the macro to run ?

Comment: If your macro is in an addin, you need to load the addin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Test_PO.xls")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Run "Data_Analysis"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

**EDIT**

If the macro is in a module then the above will help. If the macro is in a sheet say, Sheet1 then replace the line

```
objExcel.Run "Data_Analysis"
```

with

```
objExcel.Run "sheet1.Data_Analysis"
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Try this code.

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, ad, FilePath

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

For Each ad In objExcel.AddIns
    If ad.Name = "Converteam.xla" Then
        FilePath = ad.Path & "\Converteam.xla"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

objExcel.Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Test_PO.xls")

objExcel.Run "Data_Analysis_Converteam"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

**EXPLANATION**:

When you use `CreateObject`, the Add-Ins are not installed by default. Please see this link.

**Topic: Add-ins do not load when using the CreateObject command in Excel**

**Link**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213489/

You have to load the Add-In and then call the relevant macro. Also the name of your macro is not `Data_Analysis` but `Data_Analysis_Converteam`

HTH

Comment: again i face the same issue. File gets opened but i get the message Macro may not be present or maybe disabled in this file. Also the addins tab gets dissapeared sumhow if i just try to open the file with this code.Macro gets diabled sumhow while opening the file through vbs

Comment: Where is the macro? Is it in the Sheet code area or the Module Code area?

Comment: module code area. I have created it such that it can be called from an add ins tab

Comment: Which excel version are you using?

Comment: Excel 2010. Even if i remove the calling of the macro line and open the file using vbs , the macros get dissapeared

Comment: Click On the File Tab | Options. Click on the Trust Center in the dialog box that opens and then click on Trust Center Setting button on the right. Go to "Macro Settings" What option is enabled on the right?

Comment: in the location were u suggested disable all macros with notification was selected. Hence i changed it to enable all macros and ran the code but i still face the same problem

Comment: thanx a lot sid. works perfectly fine now with the add-ins mod.

Comment: hey sid can u maybe delete the link to the chat as i dont want the xl file to be viewed by every1. thanx

Comment: Hey just a follow up question . Can i maybe have sum kind of a plugin which would not require me to have a licensed version of excel which performs all the functions of the macro ?

Comment: I am not aware of any such kind of plugin :)

Comment: hey another question . I am returning a value from my vba , how can i assign it to a variable in my vbs ? i have used Set flag=objExcel.Run "Data_Analysis" but it gives me a excpected end of statement error. Also i am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); in java , how can i return this value to my java program ?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Siddhart's answer - you can load the addins you require in a VBScript like this:

```
objExcel.RegisterXLL("analys32.xll") 'For XLL addins
objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objExcel.LibraryPath & "\analysis\atpvbaen.xla") 'For standard XLA addins
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Program Files\MyAddins\MyAddin.xla") 'for custom XLA addins
```

Comment: Yes that is what mentioned in the link that I gave but then that is not the right way :) Reason being, it is not always true that your add-ins will be at `xl.LibraryPath`

Comment: fair enough - I'll delete then ;-)

Comment: OK - let's leave it for posterity then

Comment: If you see the code that I posted, I used the `for loop` to get the actual path. I had tested it with `objExcel.LibraryPath` earlier ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue, but the above solution not worked for me.
Here is what I tried and worked,

- manually opened the .xlsm file
- click 'Enable content' button from the top bar
- check the box 'Do not ask me again'
- save and close the file
- run the .vbs file again

And the error would not appeared anymore (at least for my recent trials). Hope this will work for anyone who is struggling too :)