# How to Launch an Excel macro from command line (Without Worksheet_Open Event)?

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

Is it possible to launch an Excel Macro from command line?

I don't want to use the `Worksheet_Open` event and just open the Excel File.

I need to launch specific macro that exists in the Excel WorkBook.

Comment: I suggest you use a [tag:vbs] instead. You can automate Excel via the script

Comment: I agree with brettdj. Use a vbs. If you want to run from the commandline then you will have to write a batch file and use the `Worksheet_Open` event.

Comment: Is it possible to make something like batch file using `VBS` ?

I never used it, can you please give me an example to launch `MyMacro` in `MyExcelFile.xlsm` ?

Comment: Hope this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file

Comment: Also see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530299/macro-gets-disabled-if-called-using-a-vb-script

Comment: Thanks the discussion you mentioned helped me

Comment: Is this not possible without VBS? I don't want to have to call a VBS Script via batch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally created a VB Script and launched it from the command line:

```
Option Explicit

    LaunchMacro

    Sub LaunchMacro() 
      Dim xl
      Dim xlBook      
      Dim sCurPath

      sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
      Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
      Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(sCurPath & "\MyWorkBook.xlsm", 0, True)        
      xl.Application.Visible = True
      xl.Application.run "MyWorkBook.xlsm!MyModule.MyMacro"
      xl.DisplayAlerts = False      
      xlBook.saved = True
      xl.activewindow.close
      xl.Quit

      Set xlBook = Nothing
      Set xl = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Note that while you can set the `Saved` property, it does not save the file. Use the `Save` method instead.

Comment: Thank you! Mehdi your answer worked for me too with a small adjustment. The line `xl.Application.Visible = True` was leaving open a zombie/phantom EXCEL.EXE process using up memory (found it through Windows Task Manager). Using `xl.Application.Visible = False` instead seems to eliminate the zombie.

Comment: Did you figure out how to generalize this for any code?

Comment: Nope @Lime I didn't

Answer (score 14):

Use the Windows PowerShell, it has excellent COM interop support.

I have the workbook c:\TestBeep.xlsm with a macro called "Test". This is my transcript:

```
PS C:\> $app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
PS C:\> $wb = $app.Workbooks.Open("c:\TestBeep.xlsm")
PS C:\> $wb.Name
TestBeep.xlsm
PS C:\> $app.Run("Test")
PS C:\> $app.Quit()
```

Optionally you can add in `$app.Visible = $True` to make the window visible.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure that the users have PowerShell installed ... I finally used a VB Script and launch it from command line

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site) also offers great COM support and has a lot of built-in Excel-controlling functions.  You can compile the script to an .EXE and then run it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to code in C# use this template

```
void Main()
{
    var oExcelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    try{
        //oExcelApp.Visible = true;
        var WB = oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
        var WS = (Worksheet)WB.ActiveSheet;
        ((string)((Range)WS.Cells[1,1]).Value).Dump("Cell Value");
        oExcelApp.Run("test").Dump("macro");
    }
    finally{
        if(oExcelApp != null)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcelApp);
        oExcelApp = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: It was unfortunately not possible to use C# ! The only possible option was Sheel Scripting ... Thanks anyway ! but i can't test your solution ...

Comment: not a problem, I saw this question was old. I was looking for this functionality and I wanted to give a way to do it in C# for others who may find it useful in the future.