# Calling macro in a batch script

Tags: excel, batch-processing, vba

Can I run a macro in a batch script?

like
SET HOME_PATH=%loaction% 
vba %macro%

Is it possible to call a macro in batch script?

Comment: Provide an example of a macro you would like to call. What language is it written in? How do you run it currently?

Comment: Batch script after performing its function gives output in excel sheets and Macro called 'FileOper.xlsm' need to perform excel operation like vlookup in batch script generated excel sheets. Currently macro is in seperate path which will take excel as an input from the hard coded path. I just want to include the macro inside batch script.

Comment: Related question: [How to launch an Excel macro from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881951/how-to-launch-an-excel-macro-from-command-line-without-worksheet-open-event)

Answer (score 0):

You can open an excel file from a batch script and run a macro whenever the excel file is opened, but whatever you are trying to do will probably be done better if it is not done with a macro