# log-onto terminal automatically with vbs code

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Okay, so we have just scheduled tasks (through windows) to run vbs script which runs a macro, however, our company does not allow us to store our password online, as a result the scheduled task will not allow us to access the server when we are logged off. The tasks are scheduled at a time when of course we will be logged off. In addition, we cannot change the settings on the computer to not log us off. It's a pickle.

So I was wondering would it be possible for me to schedule some vbs script that would access my virtual terminal - the name of software: Pulse secure terminal service client - and input my password as to log me in before the task is scheduled to run.

here is the vbs code that is working that we have so far

[Calling VBA macro from .vbs file throws 800A03EC error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360041/calling-vba-macro-from-vbs-file-throws-800a03ec-error)

```
Sub run_macro()
    Dim xl1
    Dim xlBook
    Dim FolderFromPath
    Set xl1 = CreateObject("Excel.application")

    FolderFromPath = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "") 
    set xlBook = xl1.Workbooks.Open(FolderFromPath & "Changed_chk.xlsm")
    xl1.Application.run "'" & xlBook.Name & "'!YourModuleName.Check"
    xl1.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Without storing your password (which your company prohibits you from doing) you won't be able to have the script supply your password to log you in.

Comment: Good point, I am looking into a macro that will simulate a left click every 5 minutes

Comment: Left-clicking every 5 minutes won't help if your security team have set up the settings to force a log off at a certain time.  If you have a business requirement to remain logged-in overnight, talk to the security team and get them to make an exception for the computers involved.  (That's what I did when I needed to have certain computers running processes 24x7 - the only requirement they insisted on was that I had to agree to perform a restart of all the computers involved at least once a week to ensure patches were applied in a timely fashion.)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I will take down the question

Comment: So you try to schedule a task on local machine to remote into virtual terminal to run this vbs? Are you allowed to set Basic Task in the virtual terminal? If so, set it to *Run whether user is logged on or not* in Security options

Comment: Indeed, you are right Patrick, however when you do this, it prompts you to save your password and the organization will not allow us do that.